# Code Style scheme and import order in IntelliJ not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In the project I am working on at the moment we have an Eclipse XML Profile  CodeStyle scheme that I have to use.

We also have to do our imports in a certain order. I have imported the codestyle and set Code Style to that scheme. Also under Java Imports I have set the order in which imports should be placed.

However, if I now do optimize imports, it keeps ordering it in the wrong way. It appears not even according to the default setting. I have tried moving around the order in the default setting, and it changes some imports, but not everything in the order it should.
I have also tried copying the settings to the project scheme, and set it to that. But that also doesn't work.

For example the order includes

- nl.*
- org.*
- others

If I do optimize imports it is ordering like

- org.*
- lombok. (other)
- nl.*

Is there any setting I am missing that blocks it using the order of the assigned scheme?

IntelliJ is up to date to the newest version.
Eclipse Code Formatter plugin is installed.

screenshot of imports as requested:

[image: Imports]

[image: Imports layout]

[image: Imports layout]

Comment: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6546-eclipse-code-formatter

Comment: Forgot to mention, but plugin is installed.

Comment: can you add screenshot with current import settings in IDEA?

Comment: Added some screenshots. If this is not what you meant, please let me know.

Comment: If the plugin is installed, then setup the plugin. IntelliJ's import order configuration has nothing to do with it - it is overridden by the plugin.

Comment: Awesome. You've pointed me in the right direction. I have unchecked the optimize imports checkbox in the Eclipse Code Formatter plugin settings, and now it doesn't override the intellij import order configuration anymore.